# Python Polars write csv resulting string data type is rounded and zero prefix missing

Tags: python, csv, python-polars

I'm using Polars to handle my excel data with big size. The result dataframe will be written to csv `pldf_csv.write_csv("C:\\mydir\\code testings\\result.csv")`. The column `3PL TN` is like a numeric ID for the table, the values of that column are like this `004087782412`. I have make sure that column datatype is in string
[image]
And then if I preview the csv from local library, the format is okay too
[image]
But when I open the file the column changed automatically
[image]
I have also tried to changed the type to Utf8 but to no avail. Is there anything I can do? My data is big and there will be several csv result so I don't want to involve looping and writing it to get the csv result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a polars problem but an Excel one.  For instance if I open notepad++ and create a csv that looks like:

```
3PL TN, weight
004092306725, 1
004092306726, 2
```

and then I open it in Excel then it'll do the same thing with the leading 0s.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/704291/205109) tells us that if there's a tab before the value then Excel will treat it as a string rather than a number.

With that info, you can save by doing

```
pldf_csv.with_column((pl.lit("\t") + pl.col('3PL TN')).alias('3PL TN')).write_csv("C:\\mydir\\code testings\\result.csv")
```

What this does is concat a tab in front of your value.  You have to put the `(pl.lit("\t") + pl.col('3PL TN')` in parenthesis otherwise alias will impact the wrong thing and you'll end up with an extra column.

Comment: works like magic, thanks so much for the clear explanation